Pair of real functions satisfying some conditions
Consider two functions $\psi$ and $\varphi$ defined on the interval $(0,c)$ where $c\in(0,+\infty)$ and they exhibit the following characteristics:

$\psi$ and $\varphi$ are continuous, positive, and strictly monotonically decreasing over the interval $(0,c)$.

$\lim\limits_{x\to c}\psi(x)=0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\varphi(x) =\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\psi(x)=+\infty$.

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi^{-1}(kx+b)}{\psi^{-1}(x)}=0,$ $\   \text{for any} \ k>1 \  \  \text{and}  \  \ b\geq 0.$

$\displaystyle\limsup_{x\to 0}\big(\varphi(x)-\varphi(k x)\big)<+\infty,  \  \text{for} \ k>1.$


I need some examples of the pair $(\psi,\varphi)\not=(-\log,-\log)$ such that
$$\psi^{-1}(s\varphi(xy))≍
\psi^{-1}(s\varphi(x))\psi^{-1}(s\varphi(y))\;\;\text{for}\;\; x,y\in(o,c) \;\;\text{and}\;\; s\geq 0.$$

What is $\sim$?

There are two positive constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ (we can have also $C_1=C_2$) such that$$C_1 \psi^{-1}(s\varphi(x))\psi^{-1}(s\varphi(y))\leq \psi^{-1}(s\varphi(xy))\leq C_2 \psi^{-1}(s\varphi(x))\psi^{-1}(s\varphi(y));;\text{for};; x,y\in(o,c) ;;\text{and};; s\geq 0.$$

The notation for what you want is usually denoted $\asymp$ (LaTeX symbol \asymp). Although in analytic number theory it is sometime denoted $\gg\ll$ (Latex \gg\ll).
